# How print in Jquery / Datatables

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, datatables

I have a table with 5 columns with the next names:

- Name
- Lastname
- Age
- Email
- Action

But i just want to print 4 of 5 of them, so.. i want to print Name, Lastname, Age, and Email, but when i found a fuction on datatables.net i didnt found how to set a class inside of TH for print the columns what i expected, sorry for my ad english

```js
(function(f){"function"===typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery","datatables.net","datatables.net-buttons"],function(e){return f(e,window,document)}):"object"===typeof exports?module.exports=function(e,c){e||(e=window);if(!c||!c.fn.dataTable)c=require("datatables.net")(e,c).$;c.fn.dataTable.Buttons||require("datatables.net-buttons")(e,c);return f(c,e,e.document)}:f(jQuery,window,document)})(function(f,e,c){var i=f.fn.dataTable,h=c.createElement("a");i.ext.buttons.print={className:"buttons-print",
text:function(b){return b.i18n("buttons.print","Imprimir")},action:function(b,c,i,d){var a=c.buttons.exportData(d.exportOptions),k=function(b,a){for(var c="<tr>",d=0,e=b.length;d<e;d++)c+="<"+a+">"+b[d]+"</"+a+">";return c+"</tr>"},b='<table class="'+c.table().node().className+'">';d.header&&(b+="<thead>"+k(a.header,"th")+"</thead>");for(var b=b+"<tbody>",l=0,m=a.body.length;l<m;l++)b+=k(a.body[l],"td");b+="</tbody>";d.footer&&a.footer&&(b+="<tfoot>"+k(a.footer,"th")+"</tfoot>");var g=e.open("",""),
a=d.title;"function"===typeof a&&(a=a());-1!==a.indexOf("*")&&(a=a.replace("*",f("title").text()));g.document.close();var j="<title>"+a+"</title>";f("style, link").each(function(){var c=j,b=f(this).clone()[0],a;"link"===b.nodeName.toLowerCase()&&(h.href=b.href,a=h.host,-1===a.indexOf("/")&&0!==h.pathname.indexOf("/")&&(a+="/"),b.href=h.protocol+"//"+a+h.pathname+h.search);j=c+b.outerHTML});try{g.document.head.innerHTML=j}catch(n){f(g.document.head).html(j)}g.document.body.innerHTML="<h1>"+a+"</h1><div>"+
("function"===typeof d.message?d.message(c,i,d):d.message)+"</div>"+b;d.customize&&d.customize(g);setTimeout(function(){d.autoPrint&&(g.print(),g.close())},250)},title:"*",message:"",exportOptions:{},header:!0,footer:!1,autoPrint:!0,customize:null};return i.Buttons});
```

Comment: You should format your code better. Also, you could have tagged this jQuery / Datatables.

Comment: Please don't post minimized code.  White space and indentation are OK (actually better than OK, they are practically required), they make developing and debugging **a lot** easier.

Comment: Did you try giving the column a class and making that class `display:none` for print?  https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className

Comment: @freedomn-m i'm newbie in Jquery i dont know how to do that

Comment: Did you look at the examples in the link I provided?  Do you have any code that looks like `...dataTable({...`?  If you could provide *your* code that you are using to create the table columns, then we can quickly tell you what you need to change, but if you can't understand the example, then you won't be able to understand an answer (as it will be exactly the same as the example...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should NEVER post minimized code - it's not easy to read, and therefore, it's hard for people to answer your question. This will lead to a negative scoring question.

Datatables are pretty easy to use, and there are plenty of examples at their website (datatables.net) for this. For this particular problem, try https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html

Assuming you are not doing server side processing, it should be as simple as this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 2 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 3 ],
                "visible": false
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Given your list, this would print

- Name
- Lastname
- Action

Email would still be searchable, but age would not.

If you only wanted to remove only the action column, as your question suggests, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 4 ],
                "visible": false
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks my men, it works. Sorry for the issues.